# what is c512,c768 of selinux process

Tags: android, linux-kernel, selinux

I got a trouble that I have a app need to access /proc entry that I create by a kernel driver and I got a selinux denied issue:

```
avc: denied { write } for pid=30200 comm="omg.flashlight" name="omg_flash_brightness" dev="proc" ino=4026534208 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

I try to solve this deny and I found I cannot allow untrusted_app to write proc:file since there will be CTS issue. I try to add a domain for the omg.flashlight APP. I use ps -Z and found the APP as follow

```
u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 u0_a89    6669  382   com.omg.flashlight
```

I try to add following setting to make it a selinux domain in seapp_contexts:

```
user=app domain=omg_flashlight seinfo=platform name=com.omg.flashlight type=app_data_file
```

and I new an omg_flashlight.te:

```
type omg_flashlight,domain;
app_domain(omg_flashlight)
```

But the result is the same, the APP still is untrusted_app.

Does anyone know about this?
I found there is c512,c768. Does anyone know what is this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to fix your line in the seapp_context file:

```
user=_app seinfo=omg_flashlight domain=platform_app name=com.omg.flashlight type=app_data_file
```

The `user=_app` starts always with an underscore.

The process running as `u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768` has the special privilege to access files within the category c512,c768. But you need to access a file type without multi level category `u:object_r:proc:s0`, so I don't think that is your problem.

Try to get your applicattion running as `platform_app` or `system_app`, depending on your device, and you should get access.

**Update**

You have mixed up `seinfo` and `domain` in your seapp_context, see above. If `platform_app` does not work, try `system_app`. 
Go to `/system/etc/security/mac_permissions.xml` and look for the `seinfo` of your app, it should be the same as defined in seapp_contexts.

```
<signer signature="your_app_signature"><allow-all/><seinfo value="omg_flashlight"/></signer>
```

If your application key is correct too, it will now run in the seapp_contexts defined domain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. c512,c768 is not the point indeed. And the point is how to make the APP as platform key or system key. Unfortunately it cannot.

Answer (score 1):

you can try making the app as System_app or platform_app only when we compile the app with local_certificate:=platform and with the device keys used to sign the app with.

for making the app as system_app u need to have local_certificate:=platform and android:sharedUserId= "android.uid.system" in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Great answer.  In Android 8, I confirmed that platform_app is using multi-user restrictions. This appends the c512,c768 to the labels.  I had to make my app a system app to allow it to share the resource.  The audit2allow tool was no help in identifying that problem.  
  
The default [seapp_contexts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/ae46511bfa62b56938b3df824bb2ee737dceaa7a/seapp_contexts) defines 
`user=_app seinfo=platform domain=platform_app type=app_data_file levelFrom=user`
  
The "levelFrom" is what is causing this restriction.